# AWS EC2 Passive FTP - Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp, pureftpd

I have pureftp running on an AWS ec2 instance. I'm trying to get it to run in passive mode which I thought was working, however I'm finding it may not be working correctly. I'm receiving the following error in FileZilla

```
Status:         Connected
Status:         Retrieving directory listing...
Status:         Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Status:         Directory listing of "/" successful
```

The odd part is some people are unable to log in while others are.

I have the following pureftp configuration

**Port Range**

```
#Port range for passive connections replies. - for firewalling.

PassivePortRange `50000 50100`
```

**PASV IP**

```
#Force an IP address in PASV/EPSV/SPSV replies. - for NAT.
#Symbolic host names are also accepted for gateways with dynamic IP
#addresses.

ForcePassiveIP            `ftp.mydomain.com` "my cname record is mapped to my ec2 public dns"
```

When I view the local port range on the server, /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range the following are open.

```
32768   61000
```

My ec2 security group has port 50000 - 50100 open

When I view my server logs I don't see much other than this every once in a while.

```
Feb  5 08:57:41 ip-172-11-42-52 dhclient[1062]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 172.11.32.1 port 67 (xid=0x601547fd)
Feb  5 08:57:41 ip-172-11-42-52 dhclient[1062]: DHCPACK from 172.11.32.1 (xid=0x601547fd)
Feb  5 08:57:43 ip-172-11-42-52 dhclient[1062]: bound to 172.11.42.52 -- renewal in 1417 seconds.
```

Anybody have any  idea where things might be going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I believe I resolved this issue. It appears as if aws was dynamically changing ip addresses. When I was referencing ftp.domain.com for my passiveip the ip that it resolved to didn't match the initial ip tied to the cname record.

The solution was to assign a static elastic ip to my ec2 instance and set my passiveip in pureftp to my static elastic ip. Thus far it appears to have resolved my issue.

Comment: Seems legit. The protocol conponents FTP uses to set up the data connection is hideously error-prone in situations like that.  Was "ftp.domain.com" originally a CNAME referencing your machine's `*-compute*.amazonaws.com` hostname?

Comment: @Michael Yes it was and it still failed. It was returning an alternate IP address. Even after I gave the machine a static ip address it still failed if I set ForcePassiveIP to use ftp.domain.com. I ended up just hard setting the ForcePassiveIP with the static ip.

Answer (score 6):

> Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead

This solved the error for me to get FTP working on AWS EC2 by adding the following lines to **etc/vsftpd.conf**

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
pasv_address=XX.XX.XX.XX
```

XX.XX.XX.XX is set to the elastic IP assigned as the public address for the instance.

Ports in range 1024-1048 and 20-21 created as Custom TCP inbound rules allowing connections from anywhere.

FTP server is running vsftpd on an Ubuntu EC2 accessed with Filezilla client.

Comment: This worked for me on Amazon an AWS instance of Ubuntu 18.4 after opening up those ports in the security group settings, thanks!

Comment: All I had to do was to open the ports in the security group as @DaveSeidman said too.

Answer (score 1):

I found some solution you can try.

https://serverfault.com/questions/821025/vsftpd-passive-reply-with-0-0-0-0-address-even-with-correct-pasv-address

I solved it by disabling listen_ipv6 and enabling listen in the config.

listen_ipv6=NO
listen=YES

Comment: This was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by setting vsftpd.conf

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
```

Reference here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54707769/1336561