# Vsftp passive mode configuration on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, vsftpd

I'm trying to configure a vsftp server on one of my ec2 instances but when I try to connect via a ftp client in passive mode I receive the error message "**Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Passive mode failed.**"

I have added to my **vsftpd.conf** file the following lines

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
port_enable=YES
pasv_address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

and I have configured ports 20,21 and 1024-1048 in my security group.

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have firewall inside the ec2 ? UFW for example? as it might be blocking the passive ports as well

Comment: Also ensure that you are using the public ip of your ec2 as `pasv_address` value

Comment: @MostafaHussein no firewall running in the ec2 instance and pasv_address is the public one

Comment: Can ensure that the security group attached to your ec2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the solution to the problem...

If the instance has and ipv6 address associated vsftpd(bug? desired behaviour? who knows...) will always return **0.0.0.0** as remote address.

You can avoid this behaviour setting this parameters:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
```